# Monodevelop and Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, monodevelop

I have installed the latest Mono Develop from the project site on Ubuntu 15.10. When I start it, I get the following errors.

```
Could not save solution: /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.sln.
Access to the path /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.sln is denied.

Load operation failed. 
Access to the path /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.sln is denied.
```

How can I fix the errors?

```
f: /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.sln
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root lib
drwxr-xr-x root root monodevelop
drwxr-xr-x root root bin
                     MonoDevelop.sln - No such file or directory
```

Steps

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mono-devel mono-complete monodevelop
```

Comment: I have added the output.

Comment: From what I understand, a solution is user-created stuff. Why are you saving your creations in a system folder?

Comment: I have just installed it, and I have not created this solution.

Comment: Hmm. Also add the steps you took for installation.

Comment: I have added the steps.

Comment: I run the steps but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. It turned out to be an odd entry in the monodevelop.desktop file. I have no idea how it happened, but here's how I fixed it:

- Open alacarte (you might need to install with `sudo apt-get install alacarte`)
- Find the MonoDevelop menu entry (I found it under Other, not Programming - YMMV) and open it
- Change the command from `monodevelop /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.exe` to `monodevelop %F`

It worked fine after that. I don't know how the command gets changed, but that's why your MonoDevelop installation things it's supposed to be opening that solution.

In my case, after I installed monodevelop I started it from the command line, right-clicked the icon in the launcher, and chose "Lock to Launcher". Since that seems like a pretty standard practice, I'm not sure how I (and you as well?) managed to end up with the same issue.

I checked both the main desktop file at https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/monodevelop.desktop and the linux packaging desktop file at https://github.com/mono/linux-packaging-monodevelop/blob/master/monodevelop.desktop and they look correct to me.